# Extracting Year and Month from a custom text field

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a data frame with a column that has information on the number of years / months the person has an account with the organization.

The field is a custom text format,

> eg: '0yrs 11mon', '15yrs 4mon' etc.

Is there a way to extract just to extract the yrs and months in to a separate column like below:

```
Member Since | Year | Mon
-------------------------

'0yrs 11mon' | 0 | 11 
-------------------------------------------

'15yrs 4mon' | 15 | 4
---------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex alternative using `str.extract` solution would be,

```
df["Year"] = df["Member Since"].str.extract("(\d+)yrs")
df["Mon"] = df["Member Since"].str.extract("(\d+)mon")
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Series.str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Year'] = df['Member Since'].str.extract('(\d+)(?:yrs)')
df['Mon'] = df['Member Since'].str.extract('(?:\s)(\d+)(?:mon)')
```

the `?:` is non capturing group notation. Which means it matches the the regular expression but doesn't capture in the output

You can also try [Series.str.extractall](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html#pandas.Series.str.extractall):

```
df[['year','mon']]= df['Member Since'].str.extractall('(\d+)').unstack()
df
  Member Since  year    mon
0   0yrs 11mon   0      11
1   15yrs 4mon   15      4
```

The extractall function actually returns a DataFrame with one row for each match, and one column for each group and so you need to unstack it.

> Use the extract all method only if you have numbers as shown in your question. More or less than two will return an error.

Comment: Thanks Mohit.. The Extractall works, but the extract does not work.. i get the error "pattern contains no capture groups"

Comment: In that case use, `(\d+)(?:yrs)` and `(?:\s)(\d+)(?:mon)`. I've made the changes to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data in excel , then this coould work:-

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_excel('filename')
month=data['Mon']  
year=data['Year']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df[['year', 'month']] = df['Member Since'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: [''.join(re.findall(r'\d',i)) for i in x]).apply(pd.Series)
```

**Output**

```
  Member Since year month
0   0yrs 11mon    0    11
1   15yrs 4mon   15     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.findall`

```
pd.DataFrame(df['Member Since'].str.findall('\d+').tolist(),columns=['Year','Mon'])
  Year Mon
0    0  11
1   15   4
```